# Java Library for XML to JSON to XML Impedance Mismatch

Tags: java, json, xml

I need a lossless conversion of XML to JSON and back again using Java.  I have used a Javascript library called [jsonxml](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/), which does it properly, but nothing in Java.

The best I seem to have found it [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java), which is mention often in Stack Overflow, but it fails testing on too many fronts.

Here are my test case code...

```
//---------------------------------------------------
import org.json.*;
//---------------------------------------------------
public class rjx
    {
    //-----------------------------------------------
    private String j2x(String json)
        {
        return(XML.toString(new JSONObject(json)));
        }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    private String x2j(String xml)
        {
        return(XML.toJSONObject(xml).toString());
        }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    //-----------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        //-------------------------------------------
        rjx o = new rjx();
        //-------------------------------------------
        try
            {
            String xml = new String();
            String reversed = new String();
            System.out.println("=======");
            xml = "<e/>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e>text</e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e name='value' />";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e name='value'>text</e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><a>text</a><b>text</b></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><a>text</a><a>text</a></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e>text<a>text</a></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<a>hello</a>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<a x='y'>hello</a>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<a id='a'><b id='b'>hey!</b></a>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<a>x<c/>y</a>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<x u=''/>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<html><head><title>Xml/Json</title><meta name='x' content='y' /></head><body></body></html>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<ol class='xoxo'><li>Subject 1<ol><li>subpoint a</li><li>subpoint b</li></ol></li><li><span>Subject 2</span><ol compact='compact'><li>subpoint c</li><li>subpoint d</li></ol></li></ol>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<span class='vevent'><a class='url' href='http://www.web2con.com/'><span class='summary'>Web 2.0 Conference</span><abbr class='dtstart' title='2005-10-05'>October 5</abbr><abbr class='dtend' title='2005-10-08'>7</abbr><span class='location'>Argent Hotel, San Francisco, CA</span></a></span>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><a /><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><b /></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e>some text<![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]>more text</e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e>some text<![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><a /></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><![CDATA[ .. more data .. ]]></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><![CDATA[ .. & more data .. ]]></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("-------");
            xml = "<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><![PCDATA[ .. &amp; still more data .. ]]></e>";
            System.out.println(xml);
            reversed = o.j2x(o.x2j(xml));
            System.out.println(reversed);
            if (xml.equals(reversed))
                System.out.println("PASS");
            else
                System.out.println("FAIL");
            System.out.println("=======");
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.err.println("error: rjx.main>>" + e.toString());
            System.exit(1);
            }
        System.exit(0);
        }
    //-----------------------------------------------
    }
//---------------------------------------------------
```

And the results...

```
=======
<e/>
<e/>
PASS
-------
<e>text</e>
<e>text</e>
PASS
-------
<e name='value' />
<e><name>value</name></e>
FAIL
-------
<e name='value'>text</e>
<e><name>value</name>text</e>
FAIL
-------
<e><a>text</a><b>text</b></e>
<e><a>text</a><b>text</b></e>
PASS
-------
<e><a>text</a><a>text</a></e>
<e><a>text</a><a>text</a></e>
PASS
-------
<e>text<a>text</a></e>
<e><a>text</a>text</e>
FAIL
-------
<a>hello</a>
<a>hello</a>
PASS
-------
<a x='y'>hello</a>
<a><x>y</x>hello</a>
FAIL
-------
<a id='a'><b id='b'>hey!</b></a>
<a><b><id>b</id>hey!</b><id>a</id></a>
FAIL
-------
<a>x<c/>y</a>
<a><c/>x
y</a>
FAIL
-------
<x u=''/>
<x><u/></x>
FAIL
-------
<html><head><title>Xml/Json</title><meta name='x' content='y' /></head><body></body></html>
<html><head><meta><name>x</name>y</meta><title>Xml/Json</title></head><body/></html>
FAIL
-------
<ol class='xoxo'><li>Subject 1<ol><li>subpoint a</li><li>subpoint b</li></ol></li><li><span>Subject 2</span><ol compact='compact'><li>subpoint c</li><li>subpoint d</li></ol></li></ol>
<ol><class>xoxo</class><li><ol><li>subpoint a</li><li>subpoint b</li></ol>Subject 1</li><li><ol><compact>compact</compact><li>subpoint c</li><li>subpoint d</li></ol><span>Subject 2</span></li></ol>
FAIL
-------
<span class='vevent'><a class='url' href='http://www.web2con.com/'><span class='summary'>Web 2.0 Conference</span><abbr class='dtstart' title='2005-10-05'>October 5</abbr><abbr class='dtend' title='2005-10-08'>7</abbr><span class='location'>Argent Hotel, San Francisco, CA</span></a></span>
<span><a><href>http://www.web2con.com/</href><abbr><title>2005-10-05</title><class>dtstart</class>October 5</abbr><abbr><title>2005-10-08</title><class>dtend</class>7</abbr><class>url</class><span><class>summary</class>Web 2.0 Conference</span><span><class>location</class>Argent Hotel, San Francisco, CA</span></a><class>vevent</class></span>
FAIL
-------
<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]></e>
<e> .. some data .. </e>
FAIL
-------
<e><a /><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><b /></e>
<e><a/><b/> .. some data .. </e>
FAIL
-------
<e>some text<![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]>more text</e>
<e><array>some text</array><array> .. some data .. </array><array>more text</array></e>
FAIL
-------
<e>some text<![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><a /></e>
<e><a/>some text
 .. some data .. </e>
FAIL
-------
<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><![CDATA[ .. more data .. ]]></e>
<e><array> .. some data .. </array><array> .. more data .. </array></e>
FAIL
-------
<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><![CDATA[ .. & more data .. ]]></e>
<e><array> .. some data .. </array><array> .. &amp; more data .. </array></e>
FAIL
-------
<e><![CDATA[ .. some data .. ]]><![PCDATA[ .. &amp; still more data .. ]]></e>
error: rjx.main>>org.json.JSONException: Expected 'CDATA[' at 41 [character 42 line 1]
```

Is there a library, perhaps a fork of JSON-java, which can pass all the tests?

By the way, I can forgive the failures for order mismatch, that is within my specification, but structure changes are not.

Comment: Question about libraries should be asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Underscore-java library has static methods U.xmlToJson(xml) and U.jsonToXml.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your exact requirements.

For example, if you see

```
<p id="foo" class='  x  '>Hello, <i>cruel</i> world.</p   >
```

does it count as "lossless" if you get the following back?

```
<p class='x' id='foo'>, <i>cruel</i> world.</p>
```

If that does *not* count as lossless, then it will be very hard to do lossless round-trips except by just escaping and quotes in the XML and calling the whole thing one JSON string. That's of course easy, but JSON won't know anything at all about what's inside.

Almost any XML parser will discard the white-space differences inside of tags; that's the designed behavior. Some also return the attributes without regard to order. An off-the-shelf conversion to JSON probably will put the attributes into a JSON hash, after which their original order is certainly gone, so unrecoverable. There are a few other issues, like whether "&#nbsp;" == "&#160;" == "&#xA0;".... Using "Canonical XML" (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n11/) would help avoid such issues.

I'm a little puzzled, though, because I can't think of an environment that doesn't have an XML parser available. Why not do no conversion at all, and just parse XML at the destination? It sounds as if the destination doesn't change the data, because if it does round-tripping obviously won't work at all. And if you send the XML, it's easier for the destination to validate it to make sure it's ok.

On the other hand, if the example above *does* count as "lossless" for your purposes, things get a lot easier. Because XML elements have significant *names* and *order* which you'll have to preserve, whatever you use should probably create both a JSON array and a JSON hash for each element. Perhaps the easiest is like:

```
[ { "#":"p" "id":""foo"" "class":""x"" },
    "Hello, ",
    [ { "#":"i" },
        "cruel"
    ], 
    "world."
]
```

I don't know of a Javascript or Java library that does that or equivalent. I have Python for it, but it's a bit large to just paste here. You can get fairly close with just this:

```
sed -E \
-e 's@>([^<]+)@>"\1"<@g' \ 
-e 's@<([^\s/>]+)(\s+[^>]*)?/>@[{"#":"\1", \2}],@g' \ 
-e 's@<([^\s/>]+)(\s+[^>]*)?>@[{"#":"\1", \2},@g' \
-e 's@<\?(\w+)(\s+([^?]|\?[^>])*)?\?>@[{"#":"#PI", "#target":"\1", \2]}@g' \ 
-e 's@<!--(([^-]|-[^-]|--[^>])*)-->@/* \1 */@g' \ 
-e 's@\s+(\w+)\s*=\s*("[^"]*")@ "\1":"\2",@g' \ 
-e 's@</([^\s/>]+)\s*>@],@g' \ 
-e 's@&#[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]+);@\\u{\1}@g' \ 
-e 's@&lt;@<@g' \ 
-e 's@&gt;@>@g' \ 
-e 's@&amp;@&@g' \ 
-e 's@&lsqb;@[@g' \ 
-e 's@&rsqb;@]@g' \ 
-e 's@"\s*([-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][-+?]\d+)?)\s*"@\1@g'
```